# What am I doing wrong in \displaystyle?

Tags: displaystyle

My code is

```
\(\displaystyle
\sum^{n}_{\stackrel{0<i<n} 
{j\subseteq i}} P(i,j) = Q(i,j)\)
```

but this is giving me an output like,

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add `\limits` after `\sum`.

Comment: Please add a complete MWE showing you problem, your code snippet works fine with me!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: `\displaystyle` would put the limits above the summation, not as you show. However are you sure you want `\displaystyle` in inline math rather than using display math?

Comment: @marmot why would you need explicit `\limits` in displaystyle?

Comment: you have accepted an answer but the neither your question nor the answer explain how you could have the non-limits setting from `\sum` in displaystyle.

Answer (score 5):

The input that you show would not produce the output that you how, in displaystyle  the sub and superscript on `\sum` are set a s limits, above and below.  It is rather rare to need explicit `\displaystyle` as that is the default style in display math, finally as shown in your output `\stackrel` is not designed for subscripts and produces different size for the first and second rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\sum^{n}_{\substack{0<i<n\\j\subseteq i}} P(i,j) = Q(i,j)\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @tomacs but then the answer to the question in the title "What am I doing wrong in `\displaystyle`?" would be "you did not use `\displaystyle`"

Comment: My suspicion is that the OP is using package `nath`. This package conflicts with package `amsmath`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek ohh the ---force--- crystal ball is string with you today:-)

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem if package `nath` is loaded and the latest closing curly brace is moved to the end of the math formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}

\(\displaystyle
\sum^{n}_{\stackrel{0<i<n}
{j\subseteq i} P(i,j) = Q(i,j)}\)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Recreated question image]

**Remarks:**

- `\displaystyle` is redefined by package `nath`, see "§8 Displayed fractions" in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nath/nathguide.pdf). The package provides `\displayed{...}`:
- According to "§11 Operators", `\\` can be used to start a new line in subscripts of big operators. The wrong `\stackrel` is not needed.

The corrected version with `nath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}

\(
  \displayed{
    \sum^{n}_{0<i<n \\ j\subseteq i}
    P(i,j) = Q(i,j)
  }
\)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Corrected result]